# Can I get a first class medical with eyesight of -4.25/-1.00 diopters?

Tags: faa-regulations, medical

I'm wondering if I'm able to obtain the FAA 1st class medical certificate with the power of -4.25 and -1 in my eyes. I heard that the difference between the two eyes must not exceed 2 diopters.

Answer (score 11):

[From the FAA's website](https://www.faa.gov/about/office_org/headquarters_offices/avs/offices/aam/ame/guide/standards/)

[image]

The key line is "*with or without correction*". So as long as your vision is ***correctable*** to the standards given you are good to go. You can find the [full AME guidelines here is you are curious.](https://www.faa.gov/about/office_org/headquarters_offices/avs/offices/aam/ame/guide/media/guide.pdf)

Comment: For those wondering, -1.00 in diopter is roughly equivalent to 20/40.