# Eye requirements for private pilots license in the US?

Tags: pilot-certification

In the next couple of years, I would like to work on obtaining a private pilot license with the goal of eventually getting my own plane. But my eyesight isn't that great in my left eye.

As a kid, I was born with amblyopia/strabismus. Did eye surgery as a kid which didn't really correct the vision. Though my eyes appear normal, my right is 20/20 and my left is 20/80/100. I should also clarify that glasses cannot remedy the left eye in terms of acuity.

So my question is will I be able to get a license? If not, that's fine, but I'd like to know so I can focus my energy and interests elsewhere.

Thanks.

Comment: The standard vision requirements are also given in [this answer](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/46997/1696).

Answer (score 0):

The guidance for vision requirements are listed [here](https://www.faa.gov/about/office_org/headquarters_offices/avs/offices/aam/ame/guide/standards/).  Basically for a private pilot distant vision must be 20/40, near vision 20/40, and no requirement for intermediate vision.  The website says

> In each eye separately with or without correction

I interpret that to mean that your left eye must be 20/40 or better.  However the final authority on this would be the FAA approved medical examiner and it wouldn't hurt to go ahead and schedule a FAA Type III medical examination and see what the doctor has to say.  Unfortunately your insurance won't cover the exam and you would have to pay somewhere around $150 for it.  However you will have a better understanding of what your options are if you want to pursue flying.  Sometimes a license can be granted but with restrictions if a pilot has a medical condition.

I hope you will be able to pursue flying and wish you the best of luck!